# Green's theorem on a trigonometric curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I'm reviewing for an exam, and picked this problem out for practice:

Use Green's theorem to evaluate $$\oint_C y^2dx+xdy \,$$

For the curve $C$, $$C = \alpha(t) = 2\cos^3(t) \hat{i} + 2\sin^3(t) \hat{j}$$

---

Here's my work so far, the bounds have me stumped.

[image: Pic]

Comment: I figured it out, turns out I was neglecting a part of the theorem.  There's a determinant that allows you to evaluate the line integral as a single integral, instead of a double integral.

Comment: Maybe you want to include your solution as an answer below

Comment: Edit: Nevermind.  Thought there was a cooldown to answering your owns question but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with.  If I understand correctly the theorem also provides this determinant that gives the set of points found in the 3rd line of the first pic.
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]